# How to change bg color of dynamic CSS class from JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic

I have a bar chart and I want to be able to assign individual fill colors to bars depending on a condition. I don't think it matters, but I am using angular-nvd3 linePlusBarChart to draw bars.

**UPDATE**
There seemingly is an issue with my local environment, possibly with NVD3 or angular libraries, I am not sure what's going on yet. I put together jsfiddle and everything worked perfectly. See the link below, the bars can have different colors.
On my local computer though, when the execution reaches the point var y = document.querySelector(...., I am getting angular error in console ->>>>> y is null.

http://jsfiddle.net/p0g9Lqu8/

Here is the HTML.

```
<nvd3>
<g class="nv-bars">
    <rect x="0" y="419" height="1"  fill="LimeGreen" class="nv-bar positive nv-bar-0-0" width="267"></rect>
    <rect x="0" y="252" height="168"  fill="LimeGreen" class="nv-bar positive nv-bar-0-1" width="267"></rect>
    <rect x="0" y="294" height="126"  fill="LimeGreen" class="nv-bar positive nv-bar-0-2 hover" width="267"></rect>
    <rect x="0" y="252" height="168"  fill="LimeGreen" class="nv-bar positive nv-bar-0-3" width="267"></rect>
</g>
</nvd3>
```

As you can see, each rect tag has a dynamic CSS class nv-bar-0-1, nv-bar-0-2.. that I would like to be able to point to from JS. NOTE: from HTML, if I use CSS, all works, but from JS loop, does not. Any help is appreciated.

This perfectly works.

```
<style>
nvd3 .nv-bars rect {
    fill:white;
}

nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-1{
    fill:yellow;
}
  </style>
```

But this, does not:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     var y = document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-' + i); 
     y.style.fill = "#ffff00";
}
```

OR this one, same result

```
var y = document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-1); // y is always null
y.style.fill = "#ffff00"; // triggers null reference error here
```

I call that JS fragment inside Angular controller in this block:

```
     angular.element(document).ready(function () {
        var y = document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-1');
        console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>===' + y); // this outputs [object    HTMLUnknownElement]
        y.style.fill = "#ffff00";
    });
```

Comment: `.nvd3` - shouldn't that be `nvd3`? - `<nvd3>` is an ELEMENT, not a CLASS - so ... `var y = document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-' + i);` is what you're looking to do

Comment: change `document.querySelector('.nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-1');` to `document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-1');`

Comment: really? so, it doesn't need a closing quote at all @MuhammadOmerAslam? :D

Comment: lol @JaromandaX that was copy paste didnt noticed, just updated it. sorry for that.

Comment: sorry, that point before nvd3 was extra, it should be nvd3 in my post

Comment: the real question is : When are you calling the JS code?

Comment: Thanks for your input, I posted the fragment where I call the JS code

Comment: `HTMLUnknownElement` That means it's found it, otherwise it would be `null`

Comment: You are right, it looks like it finds the element and it assigns the color, but for some reason, the color of the bar does not change. In console after the assignment I can see the color changed to yellow. 
y.style.fill = "#ffff00";
->>> rgb(255, 255, 0)

Comment: Was wondering what is  `nvd3`, as it looked like an `svg`, after seeing its a component for D3, I noticed it is indeed an `svg`, looks like it gets transformed into an SVG.   So your CSS selector might want `nvd3` changing to `svg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thank everybody for time and input. I finally found where the problem was and what the solution would be, so I would like to share it with the community in case anybody comes across a similar problem.

My final output into the browser is a result of combining multiple HTML/JS/CSS fragments. The issue was in timing: the JS code was attempting to refer to a tag, but it appeared the dynamic construction of that tag with its HTML/CSS was not complete at the time of JS reference.

angular.element(document).ready(.... could not do the job, but a pure JS approach from the link below - did.

https://github.com/jfriend00/docReady

I enclosed the JS block that was to check some conditions and assign colors to bars, into the docReady block. See the simplified code sample below.

```
           docReady(function () {

                for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    var k = document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-' + i);
                    // some condition goes here.....
                    k.style.fill = "green";

                }

                var y = document.querySelector('nvd3 .nv-bars rect.nv-bar-0-1');
                // this too changes color
                y.style.fill = "#ff0000";
         });
```

Worked in all major browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Safari and IE